Is there a way to have leaflet map dynamically change to the size of the viewable tab
I am trying to create code that a map is loaded full screen and fills the whole screen with a white border on the outside and has no overlap, I searched google and I could find anything on the platform that gave me a solution only a half way to set it to a specific height can anyone help me on this I’ll out my best attempt below
codepen URL: https://codepen.io/ThePencilGuy/full/PorzXRW
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 750px;
    }
    
    #map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

var map = L.map("map").setView([37.908095, -83.1023], 6);
  L.tileLayer("https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png", {
    attribution:
      'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, :)'
  }).addTo(map);


what is wrong with your attempt?

I want it to automatically change with the tab size, currently it’s constant and doesn't change,

fullscreen plugins doesn't help?

I didn’t know what that was like yesterday so I’ll research a little bit more later

Fullscreen plug-ins work but dosent work every well with maps, unless you know how to fix the bug when you scroll down it exits fullscreen I don’t think it will work
